# Normal ordering constant value in String Theory and Old Covariant Quantization

Tags: hilbert-space, string-theory, unitarity, brst, ghosts

Suppose you are approaching the quantization of the closed bosonic string for the first time (so we are in the so called Old Covariant Quantization (OCQ), and by now we know nothing about Lightcone quantization (LCQ) or BRST). We know that, for the problem of normal ordering in $L_{n}\equiv \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p}:\alpha^{\mu}_{n-p}\alpha_{\mu}^{p}:$, the Virasoro constraints on the physical states $|\phi\rangle$ are
\begin{equation}
L_{n}|\phi\rangle=0\;\;n>0
\\
(L_{0}+a)|\phi\rangle=(\sum_{p>0}\alpha_{-p}\cdot\alpha_{p}-\frac{1}{4}\alpha'M^{2}+a)|\phi\rangle=0
\end{equation}
with $a$ the normal ordering constant to be computed later. From this we have that a physical state must have a mass given by
\begin{equation}
\hat{M}^{2}=\frac{4}{\alpha'}\Big(\sum_{p>0}\alpha_{-p}\cdot\alpha_{p}+a\Big)=\frac{4}{\alpha'}(\hat{N}+a)
\end{equation}
where $\hat{N}$ is the level number operator.

We know that from LCQ we have $a=-\frac{d-2}{24}$ and from the anlysis of the mass spectrum in LCQ we have $a=1\longrightarrow d=26$ (and the same from BRST).

However my professor tried to put constraints on $a$ before, in OCQ. He claimed that for $a<-1$, we have "physical ghosts states" (negative norm), which is impossible. The reasoning is the folowing, which he explained by voice without writing anything:

At the first exicted state of the string, we have that the most generical state is
\begin{equation}
|V\rangle=\int d^{d}pV_{\mu\nu}(p)\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{-1}\otimes\alpha^{\nu}_{-1}|\tilde{0},p\rangle\otimes|0,p\rangle
\end{equation}
where $V_{\mu\nu}(p)$ is a generical polarization tensor (and I have used $\mu,\nu=0,..,d-1$ because we are in OCQ, and not in the transverse space of LC). Now, the norm of $|V\rangle$ is
\begin{equation}
||V\rangle|^{2}=\int d^{d}q\int d^{d}p\;\; V_{\beta\alpha}^{*}(q)V_{\mu\nu}(p)\langle\tilde{0},q|\tilde{\alpha}^{\alpha}_{1}\tilde{\alpha}^{\mu}_{-1}|\tilde{0},p\rangle\otimes\langle{0},q|{\alpha}^{\beta}_{1}{\alpha}^{\nu}_{-1}|{0},p\rangle
\\
=\int d^{d}q\int d^{d}p\;\; V_{\beta\alpha}^{*}(q)V_{\mu\nu}(p)\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}\tilde{\delta}^{d}(q-p)\otimes\delta^{d}(q-p)
\end{equation}
**Question 1** How to treat with that cross product between the $\delta$? I put the cross product because, in general, the two brakets can give other operators and so the tens product is needed.

However I think that the final answer is
\begin{equation}
||V\rangle|^{2}=V_{\beta\alpha}^{*}(0)V_{\mu\nu}(0)\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}
\end{equation}
Since we are in OCQ, we have still to impose the Virasoro constraints on the solution. One says that the mass is $M^{2}\propto (1+a)$; the other ones translate in the transverse polarization conditions
\begin{equation}
p^{\mu}V_{\mu\nu}(p)=V_{\mu\nu}(p)p^{\nu}=0
\end{equation}
*if $a<-1$*, the first state is indeed tachionic and so we can move to a frame in which $p^{\mu}=(0,p^{i})$. With this form of the momentum, we obtain
\begin{equation}
0=p^{\mu}V_{\mu\nu}(p)=p^{i}V_{i\nu}=0\longrightarrow V_{i0}=V_{ij}=0
\\
0=V_{\mu\nu}(p)p^{\nu}\longrightarrow V_{0j}=V_{ij}=0
\end{equation}
In other terms, only $V_{00}(p)\neq 0$. But if this is true, the norm of $|V\rangle$ is positive, even in Minkowski space-time.

**Question 2** How to obtain a negative norm state? I hoped that this reasoning would be true in open strings -because there we would have only one $\eta^{00}=-1$- but in this case we have only $p^{\mu}V_{\mu\nu}(p)=0$ and we cannot conclude that only the zeroth component of $V_{\mu\nu}$ is non-zero. I know that there must be a ghost here for $a<-1$, also because of the no-ghost theorem (all the ghosts decouple from the theory if $a=-1,\;d=26$), but I can not find it.